# Popover View Arrow Moves When Keyboard Appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover view with a search bar and search bar delegate.  When the popover view is presented it points the arrow at the button I press to pull it up as expected.  When the search field is selected and my view is pushed up, the arrow moves all the way to the bottom of the popover instead of pointing at the button it should be anchored to.  If the keyboard is dismissed the arrow slides back to where it should be in the middle of the popover.

I can dismiss this popover and manually call another one with the arrow in the right place, but I feel like that is a terrible solution.

It is being presented like this when the button is pressed

```
[over presentPopoverFromRect:self.addCategoryButton.bounds inView:self.addCategoryButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Comment: Perhaps it is anchored to the location in the view, not the button?

Comment: It does seem to behave this way, but it is presented from the bounds of the button.  How can I adjust it to the new bounds after the keyboard is displayed?  I have tried presenting it again, but the arrow is in the same place (at the bottom).

Comment: Could you pass your "moving" view as the parameter in **inView:**, perhaps that will attach it the way you want it.

Comment: I tried passing the buttons view, its super, and its super's super.  I also tried presenting it from an arbitrary rectangle and get the same unwanted movement.  Thanks for the suggestions, if you have any others I'll definitely try them.  At this point I'm thinking about just having no indicator arrow on the popover at all.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @Psiticosis ,Have u pushed your view up while showing keypad or what did u mean by my view is pushed up. And what if you change UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft to UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny

Comment: same issue . . have you found solution

Comment: I ended up just removing removing the arrow for that project.  I believe it was the odd view hierarchy that was giving me grief with that.

Answer (score 0):

let's say the button is a subview for self.view.
My guess is the popover should be presented like this:

```
[over presentPopoverFromRect:self.addCategoryButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Comment: `view.bounds` relative to `view` is the same as `view.frame` relative to `view.superview`, so this change will have no effect.